# Put modal to the left of the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to 'hack' a bootstrap modal to hang on the left of the screen and act almost like a scrolling side bar.

Any ideas on this?

Ideally, I'd like a minimal fuss & just apply some CSS to the single modal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
body .modal-dialog { margin-left: 0 }
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/o715Lj2y/).